# How can i get default prompt and get rid of "sh-3.2#"?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, command-prompt, su

Recently, i downloaded brew and npm to my reinstalled macOS, and now i noticed, when i write "su" command and write my password, i am getting this:

[su.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDbtq.png)

My problem is, I want to get old su prompt, how can i get it?

I can't even remember what was it saying when i type su command. I don't know what to do, so i couldn't try anything.

I've searched and all i found is "this is root, it is ok". I can get it is root but i want to get old look. When i type "whoami" it says root.

Thanks for all help!

> Sorry for all mistakes in my question

Comment: It's actually root. Don't worry. Type `exit` and you'd be back to your actual user account. http://ezprompt.net and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization would help you a lot if you still want to customize the prompt. Basically what's happening is that the prompt for root account is different than the prompt for your user account. It can be customized though. Refer the links above for more help or info.

Comment: I just want to get default text for it, i can't even remember what was that it just erased from my mind...

Comment: please read the archwiki link. Be willing to learn. I don't get what you want. Either change the `.bashrc` in `/root/` or type `exit` or `Ctrl-D` and you'd be back to your user account which has the old prompt.

Comment: @GLaDOS i want to change sh-3.2# to ComputerName:CurrentDirectory User$

Edit: Changed!

Comment: Type `PS1="\h:\W \u$ "` and press enter. It'd show `root` instead of `oguzhanvarsak` as you are in root. This is temporary though. Follow /u/man0v 's advice to make it persistent. Its not recommended to stay in root all the time. Don't run downloaded scripts as root if you don't trust the source.

Comment: @GLaDOS i added a comment how did i fix it, thanks for all of your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i changed it to my wish finally!

Step 0:

```
su -> password
```

Step 1:

```
nano .bash_profile
```

Step 2:

```
export PS1="\u@\h\w $ "
```

Step 3:

```
CTRL - O -> Return -> CTRL - X
```

[Result.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk0n4.png)

Answer (score 34):

1. Go to Preferences > Tools > Terminal
2. click on the folder icon in Shell path
3. Select your preferred, bash, zsh ect.
4. Close and reopen terminal

Comment: This solution worked easiest for me. Did this through my IDE and selected my zsh file. For some reason it changed to bash. Thank you.

Comment: This is correct answer

Comment: This is def the correct answer.

Comment: Had to go to bash and come back to zsh to see my regular prompt -- specific to terminal with intellij

Answer (score 2):

To set up a prompt you need to set the `PS1` variable in your **root** `.bashrc`. To use the same one as your current user's your can print it

```
echo $PS1
```

and then once you su in you can put it in your `.bashrc`:

```
PS1="\h:\W \u$ "
```

That way round, next time you login as root it'll be picked up.

Thanks to [Glados](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7942656/glados) for pinpointing the default `PS1` on mac.

Comment: `PS1="\h:\W \u$"` I think this is the original prompt OP had

Comment: @GLaDOS when i type echo $PS1 it still gives me \h:\W \u$ if i am on$. but when i type it with #, it gives something else like this: 

\s- (enter)
(tab)   \$

Comment: @GLaDOS only thing you're missing is a space `PS1="\h:\W \u$ "`

Comment: @man0v sorry. Didn't see that. There would be a space at the end.